# AWS NLB - not able to assign Elastic IP to Network Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Am trying to assign Elastic IP (recently disassociated from EC2 instance ) to an Internet facing Network Load Balancer using Edit IP Address Type option,  however Elastic IP is not shown in  dropdown  Assigned by AWS.Actually no drop down is shown.

Suggest if am I missing something or there are other way for doing the same.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you choose the right VPC? What you are doing is correct

Comment: I have only one VPC, so should not be an issue. Further for all the services am ensuring to keep the region same.

Comment: Check this video https://youtu.be/q0Sp6bT8giM?t=189 . There should be a dropdown

Comment: issue is UI shown in youtube and in other training sessions is different than current one. They seems to completely revamped the UI.

Comment: Has the NLB already been created? Maybe it can only be specified at creation time

Comment: I have deleted that NLB, and  in process to create new one. Under mapping below each subnet can see the dropdown with desired EIP. So issue is resolved. But apart from that as per doc, they should allow to assign EIP for already  NLB which has already been created.

Comment: Good to know. I suspect there must be a technical reason for that limitation

Comment: @Paolo - I think so, and thanks Paolo for help while resolving this issue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't change existing IP address** assocciation. You already have assigned all your NLB nodes to AWS provided IP. You can only add Elastic IP for new AZ association in an existing NLB. If you used all associations, you have to create new NLB.

Comment: Have added onre more screen shot from same UI, it says  -For internet-facing load balancers, the IPv4 addresses of the nodes can be assigned by AWS or you can select one of your Elastic IP addresses. For internal load balancers, the IPv4 address is assigned from the subnet CIDR. -

Answer (score 0):

You can assign EIP to NLB, follow this guide (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-attach-elastic-ip-to-public-nlb/).

Another way is to use AWS Accelerator and you can add static IP to NLB/ALB (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/latest/dg/work-with-standard-accelerators.html )

Comment: Actually, It is possible to assign EIP to an NLB and the way OP is doing is correct

Comment: @Paolo You are correct, I will update my answer.